# Change start position of Menu in master page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I click on collapse button then menu start from top of screen. But it should be start after title bar as per below image.

Code : Simple add master page. Nothing any changes on default page provide by visual studio.

[image]

Anyone have idea which properties use for this?

Comment: I don't think `Xamarin.Form` offers such flexibility. You could try to set half of the blue area (through a grid) `Background` as transparent but then the background will still be dimmed out.

Comment: Good idea! but there is one toggle button for toggle menu on title bar. In this case, I can't able to click on that button when background is transparent.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Xamarin.Form's implementation of XAML but maybe the toggle button has a `Pannel.ZIndex` or a `PreviewClick` event that will allow to handle clicks on it event if it is behind some other element

Comment: yes, but I think, it is not correct way. if any properties by xamarin form then it is better